# How to solve a problem about data when a certain percentile number is known?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Given that the 75th percentile of the data set is 6, how can we find the value of parameter a?

```
data = {1, 1, a, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7}
```

Why didn't the following method yield the value of a?

```
Clear["`*"]
data = {1, 1, a, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7} // 
  Simplify[#, {a \[Element] Reals}] &
Reduce[{Quantile[data, 3/4] == 6}, a]
```

Comment: (-1) The `// Simplify[#, {a \[Element] Reals}] &` simply doesn't make sense. Still, you're coding blindly (if you're not consulting stuff like ChatGPT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

data = {1, 1, a, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7};

q[a_?NumericQ] :=
 Quantile[{1, 1, a, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7}, 3/4]

sol = FindRoot[q[a] == 6,
   {a, Quantile[DeleteCases[data, _Symbol], 3/4]}] /.
  x_Real :> Round[x]

(* {a -> 6} *)
```

Verifying,

```
Quantile[{1, 1, a, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7} /. sol, 3/4]

(* 6 *)
```

However, the solution is not unique. Any value greater than 6 will also be valid.

```
Quantile[{1, 1, a, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7} /. a -> 100, 3/4]

(* 6 *)
```

Comment: ```Quantile[DeleteCases[data, _Symbol], 3/4]}] /.
  x_Real :> Round[x]```What does this code mean?

Comment: FindRoot requires an initial estimate. The referenced code builds the estimate by calculating the corresponding quantile for the original list excluding the unknown element.